# Online tool to graph functions in c-like languages

Tags: web-apps, graphs, programming, math

Is there a website where I can enter in functions from integers to integers in a c-like programming language (with `while` loops, `if/else` etc.) and see a graph of the results?

[This website](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) doesn't do what I want because I can't enter in iteration or recursion.

[This website](https://repl.it/languages/c) doesn't do what I want because (as far as I know) it can't show me a nice graph.

To give a specific example, I would like to be able to see a graph of this function

```
int f(int x) {
    while (x < 0) {
        x += 60;
    }
    return x;
}
```

and this function

```
int g(int x) {
    if(x < 0) {
        x = 60 - ((-x) % 60);
    }
    return x;
}
```

overlayed on top of each other to visually see whether they are visually distinct.